# Getting declaredFields of generic type T

Tags: java, generics

I have a generic class defined like:

```
 public class ExcelParser<T> {
    private Workbook workbook;

    public ExcelParser(InputStream is){
      workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(new POIFSFileSystem(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes)));
    }

    public List<T> retrieveRecordList() {
        Field[] fields = T.class.getDeclaredFields();// here will give a error
    }
 }
```

What I attempt to do is to write a generic class that cloud parse excel records to javabean `list`, but I couldn't get the `declaredFields` from a generic type T, is there any way to do that?

Comment: retrieveRecordList does not even compile without `()` - where do you use an actual instance of T in your class? If you have an instance T t somewhere then t.getClass() will do the trick for you

Answer (score 6):

You should store the `Class<T>` within the `ExcelParser` class, in order to obtain meta-information about `T` at Runtime:

```
public class ExcelParser<T> {
    private Workbook workbook;
    private Class<T> clazz;

    public ExcelParser(InputStream is, Class<T> clazz) {
      workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(new POIFSFileSystem(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes)));
      this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    public List<T> retrieveRecordList() throws Exception {
        Field[] fields = clazz.getDeclaredFields();
    }
}
```

Comment: In other word, all *generic type T* will be erased at run time, so I can't pass the class info to the *parsing class*  via the generic type but only can do that with passing the class info to *parsing class* via constructor or other method, am I get that right?

Comment: Then it seems using generic type won't help too much in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Add field classT and dummy arguments to constructor.

```
public class ExcelParser<T> {
    private Workbook workbook;

    private final Class<?> classT;

    @SafeVarargs
    public ExcelParser(InputStream is, T... dummyArguments){
      workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(new POIFSFileSystem(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes)));
        classT = dummyArguments.getClass().getComponentType();
        System.out.println(classT);
    }
```

And call constructor without dummyArguments.

```
    ExcelParser<Baz> parser = new ExcelParser<>(is /* no dummyArguments */);
```

`classT` is assigned to `Baz.class`.

Comment: I'm put off this solution by the "Possible heap pollution from parameterized vararg type T" warning it would generate.